# Create-React-App Chrome Extension - Have a second HTML and JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension created via create-react-app that injects content a webpage.

The extension's popup window is created with React using the `index.html` file in the `public` folder and the `index.js` file in the `src` folder by default.

I currently have another HTML file in the `public` folder that gets injected into the webpage via an iframe in the content script.

I want this HTML file (`inject.html`) to be created with React, rather than just vanilla HTML + JS.

I can't figure out how to do this, as I can't seem to get the HTML file in the `public` folder to use the React js file in the `src` folder to render it's content.

Is this possible? And if how how can I achieve this?

From searching around, people are suggesting ejecting and editing webpack somehow to maybe achieve this?

Or maybe reusing the index.html and doing a check in the index.js of which content to render? (Although this feels a bit hacky to me).